# How to require npm packages after installing it in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, npm

How to require npm packages after installing it in Laravel?

For example，I need package `sweetalert2`,installing it first：

```
npm install --save sweetalert2
```

Now,do I need to require it in `\resources\assets\js\bootstrap.js` file in laravel?

It's default content is like this:

```
window._ = require('lodash');

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}


window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = window.Laravel.csrfToken;
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

It looks like `lodash`,`jquery`,`bootstrap`,`axios` have been required into laravel,but the 4 sentences are different,they are like this:

```
window._ = require('lodash');
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
window.axios = require('axios');
```

**Questions：**

1、why do the 4 sentences have  differences?

2、I want to require package `sweetalert2`，how do I write it?

Answer (score 7):

You should just be able to `require` it in your `bootstrap.js` file:

```
require('sweetalert2');
```

Then (assuming you're using `scss`) in your entry .scss file:

```
@import "node_modules/sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2";
```

Also, the reason you don't have to manually attach `bootstrap` to the`window` is because it will do it automatically when it's loaded. This is because it's assumed the `window` instance will always exist as it's a styling framework. One of the reason the other libraries might not do this is because they can be used in environments where `window` isn't defined.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @zwl1619 Did this answer your question? If it did please may you mark it as accepted.

Comment: I follow you upvoted answer, as well as that from Swal documentation, but still getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: Swal is not defined`. `npm` has always been obscure to me and I'm trying to figure it out and use it once and for all. I made a `npm run watch` which returns a success if I don't put the scss part. Laravel 8 with Laravel Mix v6.0.37. Could you help me ?